# How to add pause/resume keys in python scripts in mac osx

Tags: python, macos

I wrote a python script helping my kids to memorize chemical elements. There is a 'for' loop lasts minutes and I would like to add some 'pause' and 'resume' functions by pressing some keys (as needed), in case the kids want to take a break.  Some posts mentioned "Ctrl+Z", which stops the script completely in the terminal. Others suggest using raw_input, which however needs press the keys in every cycle of the 'for' loop.   My script is below:

```
import os
import random
import time

name = 'eric'

element_table = {'H':'Hydrogen', 'He':'Helium', 'C':'Carbon', 'N':'nitrogen', 'O':'Oxygen', 'F':'Fluorine', 'Ne':'Neon', 'Mg': 'Magnesium', 'Na':'sodium', 'k':'Potassium', 'Ca':'calcium','Fe':'Iron', 'Cu':'Copper', 'Ag':'silver', 'Au':'gold', 'Hg':'mercury', 'Al':'Aluminum', 'I':'Iodine', 'Ni':'Nickel', 'Br':'Bromine', 'Cr':'Chromium', 'Si':'Silicon', 'Ba':'Barium', 'Mn':'Manganese', 'Zn':'Zinc', 'P':'Phosphorus', 'S':'Sulfur', 'Cl':'Chlorine', 'Sn':'Tin'}

temp_table = element_table

os.system("say Hello %s.  let us practice element-to-symbol of periodic element table" % (name))

while (temp_table):
    rand_key = random.choice(temp_table.keys())
    time.sleep(2)
    os.system("say what is the symbol for the element of %s" % temp_table[rand_key])
    time.sleep(1)

    time.sleep(7)
    os.system("say time is up. The answer is " )

    for k in range(0, len(rand_key)):
    os.system("say %s" % rand_key[k])
    time.sleep(0.4)

    time.sleep(2)
    del temp_table[rand_key]
    if (temp_table):
        os.system("say next question")

os.system("say The practice is over")
time.sleep(0.5)
os.system(" say See you next time")
```

Comment: Without seeing how your loop is functioning we won't be able to help you. Please consider adding your code to the question.